# Is writing kernel memory with system call available?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, windows-kernel

I know system call's uses is to communicate between use-level and kernel-level

So, Does that mean I can write kernel memory with system call?

e.g. write() is used to write kernel memory

But if what I think is available, It also relate big-security problem?

If I can't, why?

Comment: "It also relate big-security problem" - yeah... that would probably be a security issue. Note the error code `EFAULT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break your questions down one by one.

Yes you can write to kernel memory via system calls directly if you implemented one that allowed writing to arbitrary locations in memory. Whether or why you would want something like this is another question. Something like this would pose a huge security risk. For example, any process can elevate their privileges or install rootkits in the kernel easily using your system call.

However, Linux does have an interface for reading and writing to kernel memory. Have a look at [`/dev/kmem`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/kmem). It allows you to open kernel memory as a 'file', seek around and read and write to it.